# Processing tokens of ParserContext in ANTLR

Tags: java, parsing, antlr

Calling the getText()-Method on a Context-Object when parsing content with an antlr generated parser returns in case that all WS-Token are ignored in the parser (which might be the case quite often) returns a concatenation of the Token without any whitespace between them. E.g.:
Parsing a Statement like

```
Hello beautiful World !
```

with the parsing rules

```
stmnt: 'Hello' 'beautiful' 'World' '!' ; 
WS : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n')+ -> skip;
```

and then calling getText() on the Context when processing the stmnt-Rule would return the following String: "HellobeautifulWorld!"

My idea is to create a method, that iterates through the Context and concatenates all the tokens together **with ws between them**. Does anyone know if there is a method to create a **not context-specific** solution for this?

Comment: What happens if you replace `-> skip` with `-> channel(HIDDEN)` ?

Comment: Thanks for that great answer! Works fine, didn't know about the channel(HIDDEN) command. Definitely a lot **less** work for me to do.

Comment: Cool, in that case I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `-> skip` with `-> channel(HIDDEN)`:

```
WS : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n')+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

This will cause the spaces to be placed on the `HIDDEN` channel while the parser is fed from the `DEFAULT` channel. However, `getText()` will use both channels, preserving the spaces when called.